# Asp.Net Core WebApi retornando lista de objetos

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, react, asp.net-core

Estou tentando retornar uma lista de um Modelo "Plano" que possui uma lista de "Gastos", retornando apenas a lista de plano funciona, mas quando adiciono para retornar a lista de gastos da um erro no javascript.

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Controller

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public IEnumerable<Plano> GetPlanos()
>     {
>         return db.GetPlanos()
>             .AsEnumerable();
>     }
> ```

Modelo dos Gastos

> ```
> [DataContract]
> public class Gastos
> {
>     [DataMember]
>     public long Id { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public string Descricao { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public TipoFrequencia Frequencia { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public TipoGasto Tipo { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public DateTime? Data { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public double Valor { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public Plano Planos { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Modelo Plano

> ```
> [DataContract]
> public class Plano
> {
>     [DataMember]
>     public long Id { get; set; }      
>     [DataMember]
>     public List<Gasto> Gasto { get; set; }
>     [DataMember]
>     public int Moradores { get; set; }
>
> }
> ```

Chamada no javascript

> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>     fetch('Plano/GetPlanos', { method: 'POST' })
>         .then(response => response.json())
>         .then(data => {
>             console.log(data);
>             this.setState({ lista: data, loading: false });
>         });   
> }
> ```

Consulta no banco de dados

> ```
>     public IQueryable<Plano> GetPlanos()
>     {
>         return _contexto.Planos
>                     .Include(p => p.Gastos);                        
>     }
> ```

Nem esse console.log é executado, o erro acontece antes , caso eu tire [DataMember] da lista de gastos funciona.

Debugando no asp.net da pra ver que ta tudo certo ele pega os dados tudo certinho, só na hora de retornar para o javascript que da problema.

Comment: Coloque essa parte na sua pergunta: `db.GetPlanos()` o que esse método faz?

Comment: pronto, fiz um ajuste no controller que tava errado tbm, mas o erro continua o mesmo

Comment: porque você está usando o verbo `post` pra fazer um get? o.O

Comment: de qualquer forma, da maneira que vc descreve o problema, me parece que ele está na API e não no react...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leo, isto me parece erro de [referência circular](http://fabriciosanchez.azurewebsites.net/3/dica-resolvendo-o-problema-a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-system-data-entity-dynamicproxies/) que geralmente gera exceção na hora da serialização.
Adicione a linha abaixo no método `ConfigureServices` da classe `Startup.cs`, isto tende a resolver este problema:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
```

Comment: referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization

Comment: Era referencia circular msm, estava adicionando a Lista de Planos na de gastos, só removi o [DataMember] da Lista de planos e foi, vlw